# bjam for boost 1.54

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-filesystem

I've boost 1.54 installed in Linux Debian (according to [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html)). Then I installed `bjam` as follows:

```
apt-get install bjam
```

Then, in order to run a sample [tut1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html) program with `boost filesystem` I typed:

```
$ cd boost-root/libs/filesystem/example/test
$ ./setup.sh
$ ./bld.sh
```

This should result in building `tut1` file. But there is no `tut1` file in `test` folder. There is only `tut1.cpp` copied here by `setup.sh`. I suspect the `bjam` installed is not for boost 1.54. How to install bjam properly?

After typing `bjam` I get:

```
warning: mismatched versions of Boost.Build engine and core
warning: Boost.Build engine (bjam) is 03.1.16
warning: Boost.Build core (at /usr/include/boost_1_54_0/tools/build/v2) is 2011.12-svn
```

Comment: Maybe bjam is already installed with boost but only path should be specified

Comment: You don't have to, boost contians bjam. All you have to do is follow instruction: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html 
Run only script bootstrap.sh and than b2 install --prefix=PREFIX

Comment: @LukeCodeBaker, thanx, works!

Answer (score 0):

22sep2023 still gets the problem

In linux debian, I solved the problem in that way:

```
sudo ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
sudo ./b2 install


/usr/bin/b2 --version
error: mismatched versions of B2 engine and core
error: B2 engine (/usr/bin/b2) is 4.3.0
error: B2 core (at /home/boost_1_83_0/tools/build/src) is 4.10-git

/usr/local/bin/b2  --version
B2 4.10-git

sudo cp /usr/local/bin/b2  /usr/bin/b2

b2 --version
B2 4.10-git
```